# Algoritmo de multiplicación (Código Java)

Tags: java, algoritmos, java-8, matemáticas

Es mi primera pregunta. Mi problema es respecto a la multiplicacion. Debo hacer un programa que me indique la solución y se imprima de esta forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es una multiplicacion de dos numeros de n digitos. Entonces, planeé hacerlo utilizando vectores y matrices.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        //La cantidad de digitos del primer numero es mayor al segundo numero
        System.out.println("Escriba el primer numero");
        String b = entrada.nextLine(); //columnas
        System.out.println("Escriba el segundo numero");
        String a = entrada.nextLine(); //filas
        //System.out.println(b.charAt(0));
        //System.out.println(a.charAt(0));
        int n1 = b.length(); //cantidad de columnas
        int n2 = a.length(); //cantidad de filas
        int [] num1 = new int[n1]; //columnas
        int [] num2 = new int[n2]; //filas
        int [][] numT = new int[n2][n1+n2+1];
        int [] sumaT = new int[n1+n2+1];
        llenarVector(num1);
        llenarVector(num2);
        llenarVector(sumaT);
        llenarMatriz(numT);
        converSIColum(b,num1,n1); //vector columna
        converSIFilas(a,num2,n2); //vector fila
        System.out.println("-----------");
        multNum(numT,num2,num1);
        System.out.println("---------");        
        System.out.println("---------");
        sumarM(numT,n1+n2+1,sumaT);
        pasarDerechaVector(sumaT);
        mostrarM(numT);
        System.out.println("-------------");
        String numTTT="";//suma total
        int nummm;
        String aa;
        for(int i=0;i<sumaT.length;i++){
            if(sumaT[sumaT.length-1]==0){
                aa = String.valueOf(sumaT[sumaT.length-1]);
                
            }
            aa = String.valueOf(sumaT[i]);
            numTTT=numTTT+1;     
        }
        System.out.println(numTTT);
    }
    public static void llenarVector(int [] nros) {
        for(int i=0;i<nros.length;i++){
            nros[i]=0;
        }     
    }
    public static void llenarMatriz(int [][] nroT) {
        for(int i=0;i<nroT.length;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<nroT[i].length;j++){
                nroT[i][j]=0;
            }
        }        
    }
    //Guardar los digitos en el vector
    public static void converSIFilas(String num,int[] numV, int n) {
        char vc;
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            vc = num.charAt(i);
            numV[i]=Character.getNumericValue(vc);
        }
    }
    //invertir los digitos del numero en el vector
    public static void converSIColum(String num, int [] numV, int n){
        char vc;
        for(int i=n;i==0;i--){
           vc = num.charAt(i);
            numV[i]=Character.getNumericValue(vc);
            //System.out.println(numV[i]);
        }
    }
    public static void multNum(int [][]m, int []x,int []y){
        int p,q,i,j;
        int t;
        for(i=0;i<x.length;i++){
            p = x[i];
            for(j=0;j<y.length;j++){
                q = y[j];
                t = p*q;  //NO SE OPERA
                m[i][j+i]=t;
                System.out.println("empieza");
                System.out.println(m[i][j]);
                System.out.println("termina");
            }
        }
    }
    /*public static int mult(int p, int q){
        int acum =0;
        for(int i=0;i<q;i++){
            acum+=p;
        }
        return acum;
    }*/
    public static void mostrarM(int[][] m){
        for(int i=0;i<m.length;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<m[i].length;j++){
                System.out.println(m[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }
    public static void pasarDerechaMatriz(int m[][]){
        int coc,res;
        for(int i=0;i<m.length;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<m[i].length;j++){
                coc = m[i][j]/10;
                res = m[i][j]%10;
                m[i][j]=coc;
                if(j+1<m[i].length){
                    m[i][j+1]+=res;
                }
            }
        }
    }                                  
    public static void sumarM(int [][] m,int colum, int sumaT[]){
        int i,j,acum=0;
        for(i=0;i<colum;i++){
            for(j=0;j<m.length;j++){
                acum+=m[j][i];
            }
            sumaT[j]=acum;
        }
    }
    public static void pasarDerechaVector(int sum[]){
        int coc,res;
        for(int i=0;i<sum.length;i++){
            coc = sum[i]/10;
            res = sum[i]%10;
            sum[i]=coc;
            if(i+1<sum.length){
                sum[i+1]+=res;
            }
        }
    }    
}
```

Todo eso es el codigo que he avanzado. Multiplicar los vectores y los valores guardarlos en una matriz dejando un espacio por cada vez que se guarde para que al final pueda sumarlos.

Matriz: filas -> nro menor de digitos
Columnas -> nro de digitos del numero con menor digitos+ suma del numero con más digitos +1 : Esto lo hice así porque planeé separar los digitos de la suma en cada posicion (método pasarDerechaVector , tal vez tenga error ahí también no estoy seguro) y en el caso el ultimo digito sea mayor o igual que 10 sumarlo con el de la siguiente posicion y guardarlo.

Mi problema también es sobre cómo hacer que se imprima los numeros para que se vean como la imagen, además cuando se hace la operacionde multNum que hace la multiplicacióm, este no guarda ningun dato y sigue con 0.
No sé mucho de estructura de datos, a lo más sé lo suficiente sobre matrices y vectores, por lo que si pueden mejorar mi código estaría muy agradecido.

La siguiente imagen es es una idea de lo que trato de hacer, en la figura solo se ven los productos faltaría hacer la respectiva validación pero hay problemas como escribí.

[image]

Agradecería mucho su ayuda. Quiero aprender más sobre este nuevo mundo para mí.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que te has complicado un poco con eso de las matrices y arreglos. La solución es más simple de lo que crees.

El algoritmo es ir descomponiendo el multiplicador para obter las decenas, centenas, etc. Lo hacemos iterando hasta  que lleguemos al 0. En  cada iteración guardamos  el  resultado parcial  de la multiplizacion.

```
        Integer  result = 0; // Acumulador de multiplicaciones parciales
        Integer numero = 0;  // Es el multiplicador parcial
        double indice = 0;   // Es el contador de decenas, centenas, etc.
        Integer multiplicador =  Numero2; // Es el numero que vamos descomponiendo
        while(multiplicador >0) {
           // Obtenemos el número mas a la izquieda del multiplicador
            numero = Integer.remainderUnsigned(multiplicador , 10);
           // Calculamos el nuevo multiplicador (le  quitamos 'numero' al  multiplicador)
          
            multiplicador = Integer.divideUnsigned(multiplicador,10);
            // Multiplicar  el Multiplicando por numero elevado posicion que ocupa dentro
            // del multiplicador 
            result +=  Numero1 *  (numero * (int)Math.pow(10.0,indice));
            // Aumentamos una  decena
            indice++;
            // Guardamos el resultado parcial
            detalle.add(Numero1 * numero);
        }
```

La  impresión de la multiplicación Inglesa  la hacemos calculando el ancho en cada impresión. Tenemos  que iterar en forma descendente:

```
        int len=num2.toString().length()-1;
        for(int i=detalle.size()-1;i>=0;i--)  {
            System.out.println(String.format("%"+(10-i+len)+ "d", detalle.get(i)));
        }
```

Juntando todo, el programa quedaría asi:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class Multiplicacion {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer num1=15;
        Integer num2=23;
        int len=num2.toString().length()-1;
        List<Integer> detalle = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int total  = Multiplicar(num1,num2,detalle);
        System.out.println(String.format("%10d *",num1));
        System.out.println(String.format("%10d",num2));
        System.out.println("----------");
        for(int i=detalle.size()-1;i>=0;i--)  {
            System.out.println(String.format("%"+(10-i+len)+ "d", detalle.get(i)));
        }
        System.out.println("----------");
        System.out.println(String.format("%"+(10+len)+ "d", total));
    
    }
    
    public  static  Integer Multiplicar(Integer Numero1, Integer Numero2,List<Integer> detalle)   {
        Integer  result = 0; // Acumulador de multiplicaciones parciales
        Integer numero = 0;  // Es el multiplicador parcial
        double indice = 0;   // Es el contador de decenas, centenas, etc.
        Integer multiplicador =  Numero2; // Es el numero que vamos descomponiendo
        while(multiplicador >0) {
           // Obtenemos el número mas a la izquieda del multiplicador
            numero = Integer.remainderUnsigned(multiplicador , 10);
           // Calculamos el nuevo multiplicador (corremos  hacia la derecha)
          
            multiplicador = Integer.divideUnsigned(multiplicador,10);
            // Multiplicar  el Multiplicando por numero elevado posicion que ocupa dentro
            // del multiplicador 
            result +=  Numero1 *  (numero * (int)Math.pow(10.0,indice));
            // Aumentamos una  decena
            indice++;
            // Guardamos el resultado parcial
            detalle.add(Numero1 * numero);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Tienes que complementarlos con  el  ingreso  de los numeros por consola.

NOTA: Si utilizas números grandes cambias el 10 de los formats por una mayor.

Comment: muchas gracias por tu ayuda, si tal vez me estoy complicando, lo que sucede es que estoy iniciando y preparando más, igual gracias por tu apoyo.  Respecto a tu código, me salen errores repecto a las siguientes lineas:     
`List<Integer> detalle = new ArrayList<Integer>();`
`List<Integer> detalle   //En los parámetros` 
El error que me sale es: cannot find symbol (en los dos)
¿Será por la versión de Java o por el IDE?
Tengo la versión instalada 1.8 y el IDE JCreator 4.50.
De igual manera, gracias por tu respuesta.

Comment: Has puesto las  lineas:  import java.util.ArrayList; e import java.util.List; en la parte de arriba  ?

Comment: Te puse el programa  completo. La funcion Multiplicar se podría hacer con un  for en lugar de  while y hacerla mas pequeña. Ka verision también es  Java 1.8.

Comment: Tienes razón, me olvidé eso. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda.